# Importar template do VueJs de um arquivo html externo

Tags: vue.js, front-end, template

Existe alguma maneira de importar um arquivo html no template?

```
 Vue.component('porcentagens',{
data: function(){
    return {
        porcentagemSangramentoMarginal: 78,
        porcentagemPlaca: 78,
        porcentagemOLeary: 78,
    }
},
template:
```

Comment: Não é só copiar o código do html e colocar na instância Vue?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, acredito que renderizar templates de arquivos externos não seja recomendado, tantos por motivos de performance, quanto por motivos de segurança.

Porém, por aprendizado e se realmente for uma necessidade, fiz a pesquisa e descobri uma maneira eficiente de fazer isso.

1. Fazer uma requisição AJAX para receber o template em forma de string. Ex.:

   ```
    fetch("https://meu.template.externo/template.html")
   ```
2. Utilizar a função [`Vue.compile`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile) para compilar o template em uma função de renderização. Ex.:

   ```
    let compiled = Vue.compile(template_externo);
   ```
3. Utilizar a função de renderização do template compilado como função de renderização do componente.

   ```
    new Vue({
        // ...
        render: compiled.render,
        staticRenderFns: compiled.staticRenderFns,
        // ...
    });
   ```

---

Para criar um exemplo funcional, [criei um Gist](https://gist.github.com/fernandosavio/09c21e24ee23fefdd9267fa1c5650aee) com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{ teste }}</h1>
</div>
```

E abaixo está um exemplo funcionando:

```js
var template_url = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/fernandosavio/09c21e24ee23fefdd9267fa1c5650aee/raw/b2a714b18a0e46a411b1451299a9d0d173d55741/vue-teste.html";

fetch(template_url)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(template => {
        let compiled_template = Vue.compile(template);

        new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          render: compiled_template.render,
          staticRenderFns: compiled_template.staticRenderFns,
          data: {
              teste: "Olá mundo!"
          }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Realmente, não vale muito a pena. Achei que teria uma maneira mais fácil. Acabei decidindo por dividir em vários componentes menores mesmo.